# shift to second parameter and for executing script $2

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to resolve how can I do for executing the second parameter (`$2`) directly after `$1`.
To illustrate:

```
./file.sh file1.txt file2.sh
```

I'm trying to call the `file2.sh` since `./file.sh` but nothing seems to work. And I don't know how should I use the "shift"...
Somebody could help me, please ?

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you are trying to do ?

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to achieve. Please clarify what you mean with "executing parameter", and whether you want to run one script from the other (`file2.sh` from within `file.sh`) or as a sequence (first `file.sh`, then `file2.sh`).

Answer (score 0):

You would like sth like that?

```
./file.sh file1.txt && file2.sh
```

It will execute file2.sh script only when file.sh script ends with zero status(no error).

You can also use `||` instead `&&`. It will run second script if first fails.

Comment: `foo || bar` will run `bar` only if `foo` fails. `foo; bar` to run both regardless.

Comment: True, my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

In `file.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

first="$1"
shift

# Run the rest of the command line as a command
"$@"
```

This will put the first command line argument into the variable `first` and then shift off that value from the positional parameters.  The last line of the script will execute the remaining positional parameters as command.

```
$ ./file.sh hello echo world
world
```

Comment: You should probably prefix that last line with `exec` to avoid forking an unnecessary new process.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, if it's the last thing the script does, but not otherwise. I don't know what the OP's script needs to do...